# Compile errors in ActionBarSherlock using api 4.4.2

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have this code in the ActionBarSherlock

```
@Override
public boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(View child, AccessibilityEvent event) 
{
    if (super.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(child, event)) {
        // Add a record for ourselves as well.
        AccessibilityEvent record = AccessibilityEvent.obtain();
        onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(record);
        // Populate with the text of the requesting child.
        child.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(record);
        event.appendRecord(record);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
    info.setScrollable(isScrollableForAccessibility());
    View selectedView = getSelectedView();
    if (selectedView != null) {
        info.setEnabled(selectedView.isEnabled());
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
    event.setScrollable(isScrollableForAccessibility());
    View selectedView = getSelectedView();
    if (selectedView != null) {
        event.setEnabled(selectedView.isEnabled());
    }
    event.setCurrentItemIndex(getSelectedItemPosition());
    event.setFromIndex(getFirstVisiblePosition());
    event.setToIndex(getLastVisiblePosition());
    event.setItemCount(getCount());
}
```

And I get compile errors on super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event); and a few other methods.

Would anyone know why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: And the errors are... what, exactly?

Comment: Error is that the calls require api level 14 and I have set it to 8.  But that is confusing because I explicitly set mine to 4.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complaint is that your `android:minSdkVersion` is set to 8, and that code is referring to classes, methods, or fields that were not added until API Level 14.

If you are attempting to modify ActionBarSherlock and compile it yourself, you can either add the appropriate code to deal with this (checking `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`) and add the `@TargetApi()` annotation to stop Lint from complaining.

Comment: thank you. What happens if I use ActionBarSherlock and leave my minSdk at 8? Will the app crash for people who have android version 8 on their devices?

Comment: @Genadinik: Well, so far, it hasn't. These are all callbacks, ones that probably simply are not called on older versions of Android, and therefore are safe. Lint does not distinguish these cases from anything else, though, which is why Lint yelps.